# Uninstall Windows 8 and keep Ubuntu 12.10 UEFI

Tags: 12.10, uninstall

I didn't find any question about this.

I have a computer with pre-installed Windows 8, UEFI interface. Is it possible, and if so, how to remove Windows 8 completely and just keep Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just need to remove the Windows 8 partition using disk usage analyzer or you could alternatively do a fresh install of ubuntu, while in the setup for ubuntu just select remove windows and use ubuntu (all depends if you mind losing data or not if you do the removing the partition is easier)

for more info look here [Partition help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition)

Comment: well, problem with the second suggestion is when in the live ubuntu installer it dont see windows 8. For Ubuntu there isnt any other OS installed. So I dont know how that will work out. And I really dont want to do a fresh install... And how wil the boot be after I just format the win8 partition?

Comment: if you remove windows 8 the boot should be fine thats how i firstly removed windows 7 when i put ubuntu on

Comment: Isn't it a difference between a Win7 and Win8 install? Secure Boot, EFI etc ?

Comment: yes but the ubuntu bootloader should override Windows 8 boot.  In many different circumstances when you install Ubuntu it overrides any other OS's bootloader and you are greeted with Ubuntu's

Comment: Okay! Then after removing the win8 partition, I can use Boot-repair in Ubuntu Live USB to fix the boot maybe?

Comment: yeah if you use the boot-repair option on the ubuntu disk you will fix the bootloader